# Load XML layout by tapping EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

I am totally new in Android.
I like to load the layout xml by tapping the EditText.
That particular xml is populated with buttons with texts. When the user press one of the buttons, the text on the button will be displayed in the EditText.
I have two problems.

```
(1)EditText IDEditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IDeditText);
```

In that line, IDEditTxt  is always null even though IDeditText is sure inside the R.id.I tried all approaches I could find from the internet like clean, delete the xml, rewrite the xml. I tried all, but still have problem.
      However the text inside that EditText can be read for another purpose. I don't understand why IDEditTxt is walays null and but the text inside that EditText can be read.

`new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("New Tracker").setView(addView)
                .setPositiveButton("ADD", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        addWord((TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.IDeditText));
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();`

(2)How can I implement loading the layout xml by tapping the EditText. Then the text displayed on the button will be displayed in that EditText.

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend you to take your time and get a good book on Android. Based on your question, there are many things that you don't understand correctly, and it makes it hard to provide an answer for your question.

Comment: @Egor Yeah that is for sure. What I am doing is learning and developing at the same time. As I am rushing for the product to finish under certain timeline, I don't have time to learn. That is why I go together. May I know what is the best approach for that problem, rather than asking me again to read a book? Yeah I am also reading a book.

Comment: I don't understand. If findViewById(R.id.IDeditText) always returns null, how does it 'work' in your AlertDialog?

Comment: @JustinJasmann final View addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add, null);is used before the AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In that line, IDEditTxt is always null even though IDeditText is sure inside the R.id....I don't understand why IDEditTxt is walays null and but the text inside that EditText can be read.

Your `EditText` exists in your `Layout` file but the `EditText` object you try to declare and use is `null` until you `inflate` your `layout`. You need to `inflate` the `layout` first, either by using `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);` or by using the `inflater` as you do before the `AlertDialog`

> (2)How can I implement loading the layout xml by tapping the EditText. Then the text displayed on the button will be displayed in that EditText.

It's usually best not to create separate `layouts` in the same `Activity` like this. You may run into errors of  trying to use a `View` that is in the first `Layout` you inflate or efficiency problems. You should create a `Layout` for the `Actvity` and use that for the whole thing unless you have a specific reason you can't. You can either start a new `Activity` when the action happens with the required `layout` or set the `visibility` of the `Buttons` to `gone` then make them `visible` after the action occurs. Hope this helps a little and the suggestion of going through a book and tutorials is a really good idea. It may take more time now but will surely save you time after you understand how the framework operates.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. If it is not a good idea, can I ask you another way? The thing I like to implement is when the user press the EditText, I like to display the screen for the user's choise rather than user has to key in. Only four texts i like to displayfor the user like Vehicle, Pet, Human , Others. Then user make a choise. What could be the best way for that user input. Then the selected text will be displayed in the EditText. Thanks

Comment: Your suggestion is good. I should understand how the framework operates. Is there any tutorial for that? Thanks

Comment: According to your suggestion, I changed as final View            addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add, null);  EditText IDEditTxt = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.IDeditText);
if(IDEditTxt != null)
{
IDEditTxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() { 
 public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),((EditText) v).getId() + " has focus - " + hasFocus,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}});
} But it never goes inside this loop IDEditTxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener().

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you are trying to achieve as far as the user input. But it sounds like your options, as far as I can tell, are use different `Activities` or change the `Views` `visibility` according to what you need. I'm also not sure what loop you aren't going into...its really difficult to read code in a comment. You may want to open up a new question with the updated, relevant code and explain the problem better. I'm glad we got you going. As far as tutorials, you should go through the docs and google as some may be good for you to understand that aren't good for others